# Finding and removing files older than 30 days

Tags: files, find, delete

I am looking to clear the users files older than 30 days. The following bash script works perfectly fine. However, I am looking to remove the "No such file or directory" error shown in the output as I have my own echo. Can anyone help please?

**Code:**

```
if [[ $(find /h/$USER/*.txt -mtime +30) ]]
then
    find /h/$USER/*.txt -mtime +30 -print -exec rm -f {} \;
else
    echo "No txt files to del"
fi
```

**Output:**

```
find: stat() error /h/username/*.txt: No such file or directory
No text files to del
```

Comment: Instead of simply suppressing the error output (which could also suppress error you actually wanted to see), you could add an existing old file to the list via "or" and check whether more than this one file is given back.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I do it, runs on a bunch of directories we want cleaned nightly.

```
find /h/$USER -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

Can't say if it's the best or worst way to do it, but it's been running for years without any issues, actually a collection of cruft cleaners, all same syntax, no issues, so I guess it's good enough for production.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're using the shell globs instead of `find` to list the txt files (it will also exclude hidden txt files, and if any `.txt` files are of type directory, it would descend into them to delete all old files there). Shells like `bash`, when the glob doesn't match any file, pass the glob as-is to `find` and `find` complains about that non-existing `*.txt` file.

You could just do:

```
LC_ALL=C find "/h/$USER/." ! -name . -prune \
  -name '*.txt' ! -type d -mtime +30 -print -exec rm -f {} + |
  grep '^' > /dev/null || echo >&2 No text files to del
```

The `grep` is to check whether `find` produces any output (no errors) so we output the *No text files to del* message if it didn't (remove the `> /dev/null` if you do want to see the files that we attempt to delete). Note that we lose the exit status of `find` in the process.

You could also use `zsh` instead whose globs can check files ages (you're already using `zsh` syntax by not quoting that `$USER`):

```
oldfiles=(/h/$USER/*.txt(NDm+30^/))
if (($#oldfile)); then
  rm -f -- $oldfiles
else
  echo >&2 No text files to del
fi
```

In any case, for both `-find -mtime +30` and `zsh`'s `m+30` glob qualifier, note that it selects files that are 31 days old or older, as it compares the age in terms of integer number of days. A file that is 30 days and 23 hours old would not be selected because its age is rounded down to 30 days which is not greater than 30.

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to redirect error to /dev/null. so error will not be displayed

```
find path -type f -daystart -mtime +30 -exec rm -rvf {} \;  2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

The find command usually requires a specific type (f for file, d for directory, b for block device, c for character, etc) associated with your search if you are annotating wild cards.  For this situation it may be more conducive to also use a for loop, instead of an if statement, also using the --max-depth option maybe useful for finding hidden files/

Code:

```
    for i in $(find /h/$USER/ -type f -name "*.txt" -mtime +30 2> /dev/null);
    do
    rm -rf  $i 2> /dev/null;
    done
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming to delete file of December 
first list the file
ls -l|grep "Dec"
second if u r satisfied, go for delete
rm `ls -l|grep "Dec"` 
Let me know your feedback. :)

Comment: what if it is not Dec?

Comment: What if a file or directory is called Dec?

Comment: What if a file *containing* `Dec` in it's name? Even worse, what if there is a file named `*` in a subdirectory named `Dec /home/user/`? (note the space).