# Generate a shell script which will only keeps 7 days files and deletes other days

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

In a backup directory I want to keep all 7 days generated files and want to delete the older days.

I tried with the -mtime option and observed the script for 3-4 days it was working. But after 5-6 days it stopped working. So deletion didnt happen and directory is full now. It seems like the -mtime is not working.

Please note also I have a cron running which automate this.

```
10 3 * * * su - cassandra -c /opt/cassandra/scripts/backup_cassandra >> /tmp/backup.log
```

Here is the script I m using :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -x
export PATH=/opt/dse/bin/:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0//bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
. /opt/cassandra/.env # source functions & password
# First we delete backup files older than 8 days.
find /data_cassandra/cassandra/backup/ -name "dc_east__*" -mtime 8 -exec rm {} \;
# cd to where the scrips are.
cd /opt/cassandra/scripts/
# And start the backups.
./backup.sh start -all # Kick off a full backup
```

Please help in a solution to this.

Comment: mtime is last modified time. Are you sure the generated files are untouched? Have you tried adding the `-f` (force remove) flag to `rm`?

Comment: You have a few options, one being: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386714/finding-and-removing-files-older-than-30-days  second https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102752/remove-all-files-created-before-a-certain-date/102767#102767

Answer (score 1):

You are `find` ing files EXACTLY 8 days old. `man find`:

> ```
>    A numeric argument n can be specified to tests (like -amin, -mtime, -gid, -inum, -links, -size, -uid and -used) as
>    +n     for greater than n,
>    -n     for less than n,
>    n      for exactly n.
> ```

So - try `-mtime +8`